# Web API, consumption from mobile app when cors credential set to true

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm using Cookie based authentication

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/api/Login/LogoutRedirect"),
    SlidingExpiration = true
});
```

so to get claimsidentity

```
var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
var EmailID = claimsIdentity.FindFirstValue(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email);
```

have to use credential,
In web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

and from clientside "withCredentials: true". But

> Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials
>   flag is true.

Then, How can I proceed to consume the hosted web service from the mobile app.

Comment: hey, does no one seen this yet.